# css label and input question

Tags: css

I have the following css for my label and input:

```
label {
    display:block;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#444;
    margin:5px 0;
}

label.notification {
    clear: both;
    color:#200;
    margin:5px 0;
}


input {
    width:300px;
    padding:4px;
    border:none;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;
    font:90% Verdana;
    color:#777;
}
```

I want it so that when I have a input and label notification in one line. How can I do this? currently it is always on a separate line.

This is how I will use it:

```
<label id="date">Date</label>
<input id="datepicker" name="datepicker"/></label>
<label class="notification">You need to enter a date</label>
```

datepicker and notification needs to be on the same line, but label (date) and datepicker needs to be on a different line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the `display: block` in your CSS for `label`.

**Edit:**

As per your recent edit and comment. You just need to append a `display: inline` to your `label.notification`. As currently, it will inherit the `display: block` from the parent `label` styles, as the rules cascade down in CSS.

Comment: I want to have two type of label one that can be used for a new line with an input and one that doesn't ...

Comment: So, the `label` in question is the one with the notification class? if so, simply append a `display: inline` to `label.notification`